# Rails Viewpoint Send-message attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, exchangewebservices, sendmessage

I've incorporated viewpoint gem to send emails using Microsoft exchange services. I don't have any issues of sending plain html email. I am not able to send a email with document attached. Someone please help me in this.

please find the sample below

```
endpoint = "http:///.asmx"
ep_user = ""
ep_password = ""
viewclient = Viewpoint::EWSClient.new ep_user, ep_password

view_client.send_message (:subject => message.subject, :body => message.body,   :body_type => "HTML")
```

-Raj

**Solution for my problem updated on 04/27/2016**

I tweaked my code in such a way to make it workable

```
mail(:from=>"", :to =>"", :subject => "", :doc_path => 'public/images/1.doc')

endpoint = "http:///.asmx"
ep_user = ""
ep_password = ""
viewclient = Viewpoint::EWSClient.new ep_user, ep_password
data_file = message[:doc_path].value
data = [File.open(data_file), "r"]
view_client.send_message (:subject => message.subject, :body => message.body,   :body_type => "HTML", :file_attachments => data)
```

Comment: Raj, let me know if my answer helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `send_message` options hash accepts a `file_attachments` option as explained in the gem's [code](https://github.com/WinRb/Viewpoint/blob/master/lib/ews/message_accessors.rb#L36). This option should be of type `Array<File>`. So I guess your code would look like:

```
...
array_of_files = [File.join(Rails.root, 'whatever_directory', 'whatever_file.ext')]
view_client.send_message (:subject => message.subject, :body => message.body, :body_type => "HTML", :file_attachments => array_of_files)
```

**Update**:

Seems gem is broken for the case when you try to send a message with files (I think messages are just kept as drafts and not sent, only files are). So I've updated the gem to fix this case, let me know if it works correctly. Import gem from my repo like this on your **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'viewpoint', :git => 'https://github.com/durnin/Viewpoint.git'
```

And try the above code again. (remember to do `bundle install` after updating **Gemfile**)

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, Thanks for your reply. partially it worked.., When I add :file_attachments as a paramater my entire message.body goes away. I got an email with attachment but no body over there

Comment: @Raj How strange! Maybe try with the `inline_attachments` instead to see if that happens also...

Comment: @Raj I've updated my answer - last try :). Let me know if this time works.

Comment: @Raj, were you able to try it? I added the `bundle install` comment to the answer in case you missed it.

Comment: @RodrigoMartinez your example didn't work, with this minor change it works for me
```ruby
array_of_files = [File.open(File.join(xxx), "r")]
view_client.send_message(xxx)
array_of_files.each { |f| f.close }
```